# pgfplots - How to rotate extra x tick labels

Tags: pgfplots, rotating, ticks

I made a pgfplot with lots of `extra x ticks` and `extra x tick labels`. But unfortunately it looks really confusing. Therefore I want to rotate them.

First I tried `xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=east}` but this didn't work (I suspect it refers to the regular ticks, which I don't have).

Then I tried `every x tick/.style={xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=east}}`, which failed, too.

Does on of you know a solution for rotating the `extra x tick labels`?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
    xmin=-0.999 ,xmax=70.99,
    ymin=0, ymax=12.5,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
    extra x tick labels={L100, L50P50, P100, P50B50, B100, B50L50, L100, L50C50, C100, C50B50, B100, B50C50, C100, C50P50, P100},
    extra x tick style={grid=major},
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a `tick label style` within the `extra x tick style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
    xmin=-0.999 ,xmax=70.99,
    ymin=0, ymax=12.5,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
    extra x tick labels={L100, L50P50, P100, P50B50, B100, B50L50, L100, L50C50, C100, C50B50, B100, B50C50, C100, C50P50, P100},
    extra x tick style={
           grid=major,
           tick label style={rotate=90} % <-- this is added
           }
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That said, if all your ticks are `extra` ticks, why use `extra` ticks in the first place?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=16.5cm,
    height=7cm,
    xmin=-0.999 ,xmax=70.99,
    ymin=0, ymax=12.5,
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
    xticklabels={L100, L50P50, P100, P50B50, B100, B50L50, L100, L50C50, C100, C50B50, B100, B50C50, C100, C50P50, P100},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm so glad you included the first example. I have a graph where not all ticks are extra ticks and I need only the extra ticks to be rotated (because they're text, whereas the regular ticks are numbers), and I wouldn't have known how to do it had you only included the second example. Thanks!